# Button inside a popup with vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have used the vue2-google-maps package to make a custom popup. In my custom popup I have placed a button which should open a new popup in the place of the old one.

Html

```
<gmap-info-window
  :options="infoOptions"
  :position="infoWindowPos"
  :opened="infoWinOpen"
  @closeclick="infoWinOpen=false"
>
  <div v-html="infoContent"></div>
</gmap-info-window>
```

Javascript for the first popup. The

```
    toggleInfoWindow: function (marker, idx) {
        this.infoWindowPos = marker.position;
        this.activeMarker = marker;
        this.infoContent = this.getInfoWindowContent(marker);

        //check if its the same marker that was selected if yes toggle
        if (this.currentMidx == idx) {
          this.infoWinOpen = !this.infoWinOpen;
        }
        //if different marker set infowindow to open and reset current marker index
        else {
          this.infoWinOpen = true;
          this.currentMidx = idx;
        }
      },

      getInfoWindowContent: function (marker) {
        return (`<div class="card">
  <div class="card-image">
    <figure class="image is-4by3">
      <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png" alt="Placeholder image">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-content">
        <p class="title is-4">${marker.name}</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      ${marker.description}
      <br>
      <time datetime="2016-1-1">${marker.date_build}</time>
       <button @click="getSecondPopUp">Get second popup</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`);
      },

    getSecondPopUp: function () {
        console.log("why don't you work?");
}
```

The problem is that when I click on the button the second method does not get executed. Does anyone know why that might be and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[`v-html`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) only renders raw HTML. The HTML that you are returning from the `getInfoWindowContent` method is a Vue template which must be rendered directly by a Vue component (and depending on your setup, if you're using webpack then it's likely that the templates will be compiled with [`vue-loader`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader) and not at runtime).

I'm not familiar with the `vue2-google-maps` package, but to achieve what you want, you should not use `v-html` and instead put the Vue template source directly inside `<gmap-info-window>`. Replace all of the `${marker.description}` string interpolations with Vue template interpolations `{{ activeMarker.description }}` (assuming `activeMarker` is declared upfront in the component's `data` object in order for it to be reactive and renderable inside the template). You may need to use `v-if` to control the visibility of parts of the template that access `activeMarker` in case `activeMarker` is null (unless the `gmap-info-window` component does not render its slot if the `opened` prop is false).

Ideally `v-html` should never be used, for one it makes [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) possible.

Comment: Thanks, for answering. The problem is that when i do not put inside a v-html I only see markdown, and the binding doesn't happen.  I have full controle about the html, so thats why I used it. I changed it to a template and the template works normaly (with the {{}}.

Comment: But now I see only the markdown and the bindings don't happen. In the vue dev tools I see that both of them exist, but the binding doesn't happen that way

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a popup done with Vue, instead of the one given by maps. Try this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/@soldeplata/popper-vue